# Why doesnt this Combinatoric work two ways?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> There are two distinguishable flagpoles, and there are $19$ flags, of which $10$ are identical blue flags, and $9$ are identical green flags. Let $N$ be the number of distinguishable arrangements using all of the flags in which each flagpole has at least one flag and no two green flags on either pole are adjacent. Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by $1000$.

Method One: Arrange the blues then divider then greens.

> $BBBBBBBBBB$ then there are $9$ places for a flag divider $X$. In turn, $BBBBBBBBXBB$ then there are $\binom{12}{3} = 220$ places for pluggin in $G$'s. In total: $220 \cdot 9 = 1980$.  Then you add $2\binom{11}{8} = 2310$.

Method Two: Arrange the blues then green then divider.

> $BBBBBBBBBB$ then there are $\binom{11}{9}$ locations for Green $=G$. Then: $GBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBB$. Then there are $18$ places to locate the divider. $\sum = 18(55) = 990$.

Which gives the wrong answer?

Comment: With the second method you miss all arrangements containing $GXG$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, but why dont you miss such arrangements in the first one?

Comment: Concerning the green flags the $X$ is just another $B$, apart from the end positions. See true blue anil's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365698/how-many-ways-to-arrange-the-flags of which this question is for all practical purposes a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd method is wrong.

Dividing before arranging throws up more possibilities due to creation of more "gaps"

Note that the "divider" could be right at the end, e.g. G X B B ....

that is why the $2\cdot{11\choose 8}$ is added.

Comment: I find that 3 separate answers using different approaches, all yielding the same answer, were given when you posed the main question. I hope you have understood by now.